# Ubuntu to list relevant security advisories

Tags: ubuntu, security, debian, apt

If I want to find out what security updates there are on a redhat/centos server and the coresponding security advisory I can run this command:

```
yum --security list-security
```

That would include data such as:

```
RHSA-2013:0132 security autofs-1:5.0.1-0.rc2.177.el5.x86_64
RHSA-2013:0131 security gnome-vfs2-2.16.2-10.el5.x86_64
RHSA-2013:0135 security gtk2-2.10.4-29.el5.i386
RHSA-2013:0130 security httpd-2.2.3-74.el5.x86_64
RHSA-2012:1590 security libtiff-3.8.2-18.el5_8.i386
RHSA-2013:0120 security quota-1:3.13-8.el5.x86_64
RHSA-2013:0129 security ruby-1.8.5-27.el5.x86_64
RHSA-2013:0129 security ruby-libs-1.8.5-27.el5.x86_64
RHSA-2013:0122 security tcl-8.4.13-6.el5.x86_64
```

This way not only do I know what packages need to be updated, if I want I can also find out what the security risk is in detail by looking up the RHSA.  Basic, and very handy information to have.

The closest I could figure out on ubuntu is:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -s| grep ^Inst |grep -i security
```

Unfortunately this only shows me that there are security packages that need to be installed.

Is there a native way to find out the related security advisories?  By native, I mean without having to use a third party package.

Comment: I suppose opening a web browser and visiting http://www.ubuntu.com/usn is not an option you prefer?

Comment: You'll probably have to address this issue to the Ubuntu folks.  I'm not sure anybody here can help you.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the option you gave:

```
apt-get -s dist-upgrade |grep "^Inst" |grep -i securi
```

You could try:

```
unattended-upgrade --dry-run -d
```

and

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p
```

([Seen on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/217999/75668))

Comment: None of those appear to include the relevant security advisory, such as :  USN-1680-1 for moinmoin

Comment: Sorry, you get to [look those up yourself](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn). I don't think Canonical has provided a way to do exactly what yum-security does yet.